# Including proc sort in proc sql

Tags: sas

Below sample data is from oracle database

```
promo   flag
vijay    a
vijay    b
vijay    c
sam      b
sam      g
sam      c
```

I have one proc sql statement connected to oracle(though i have not mentioned oracle connection below)

```
proc sql;
create table a as select *from new;
quit;
```

then two proc sort statement based on above dataset a.

```
 proc sort data = a;
 by promo descending flag;
 run;
 proc sort data =a nodupkey out =new1;
 by promo;
 run;
```

Now I want do these two proc sort statements inside proc sql statement itself. Any idea how to do?

Comment: Please show a few records of an example of the data you have, and the output data you want.  I can never remember which record SORT NODUPKEY keeps.  It looks like you are maybe trying to select one record per value of PROMO, selecting a record with the maximium (or minimum?) value for flag?

Comment: data new;
input promo $ flag $;
datalines;
vijay a
vijay b
vijay c
sam b
sam g
sam c
;
run;

Comment: First i need to sort by promo and descending flag, then get the highest flag for each promo and send the remaining to new dataset new 1

Comment: Can there two records with the same value for promo and same value for flag?  Suggest editing your question to have the sample data in it. For your sample data, the answer is no, which makes this a bit easier.

Comment: no two records  with the same value for promo and same value for flag

Comment: If you want to get only one record per key value group even when they have different values for non-key variables then SAS's implementation of SQL cannot do that.  It you push the SQL into your database then you can use windowing functions that newer SQL implementations support to generate row numbers and select only the first row for each by group.

Answer (score 1):

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select distinct promo,flag from new group by promo having flag=max(flag);
quit;
```

Comment: How does it sort the data?

Comment: how to create out =datatset?

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` clause is what tells it to create a dataset, in this case the output dataset is `want`. You should add an `ORDER BY` clause to specify the order, but in practice SAS will order when you use a `GROUP BY`.  The `HAVING flag=max(flag)` is what is selecting the records with the maximum value of flag within the values of PROMO so that is doing what the first proc sort with descending option did for you.

Comment: @geethaanand you want the functionality of a sort but you don't necessarily need a sort. In this case you're looking for the max value and that's what's being returned. If you are using pass through though, this may not work.